# Does a graphics card need leeway power?

Tags: power, amd-radeon

So I'm looking to buy a new graphics card that says it needs 150 watts to run, the AMD Radeon 270. I can get it the 150 watts, but does it need some extra power as leeway or will it be just fine on only 150 watts?

I got the 150 watts needed from tom's hardware's page on it.
http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/radeon-r9-270-review-benchmarks,3669.html

My power supply is 600 watts, but i only have one extra 6 pin connector to hook up to the video card.

Comment: What do you mean by leeway power?

Answer (score 0):

the graphics manufacturer stated power is maximum, but as a rule of thumb, most tech savy people use atleast a 430W psu or higher like a corsair CX500W power supply to power a Radeon R9 270 graphics card with the cpu and everything else

it all depends on what else you have in your system, what cpu?, what motherboard?, how many harddrives/ssds

Answer (score -1):

Where are you getting the 150 watt statistic? Not all cards are created equal, and unless you have a range of consumption statistics you're looking at potentially killing your card.

If 150 watt is the maximum, then you should be fine providing it exactly that, provided you don't plan on under or over clocking the GPU's performance. Underclocking or overclocking the GPU will subsequently lower or raise the power consumption, of course.

I would recommend attempting to retrieve more accurate power consumption statistics from the manufacturer.